# Cannot see the JTextField after adding JLabel and JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I am trying to add the basic `JFrame` in which I add the `JLabel`, `JButton` and the `JTextField` in it. But only two things appear in it at a time.

I want all three to appear in the frame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    JFrame f;
    JLabel l1;
    JButton b1;
    JTextField tf1;

    public Main(){
        f=new JFrame();
        l1=new JLabel("This is the new Label");
        l1.setBounds(10,20,50,30);
        b1=new JButton("Submit");
        b1.setBounds(50,70,90,40);
        tf1=new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(70,100,90,40);

        f.add(l1);
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(tf1);
        l1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLayout(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Can you give an example basic will be prefered

Comment: Can you follow instructions? See my second point.

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - plenty of examples

Answer (score 0):

See whether below code works for you. I have only changed these lines in your code:

```
f.add(l1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
f.add(tf1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//f.setLayout(null);
```

Full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
  JFrame f;
  JLabel l1;
  JButton b1;
  JTextField tf1;

  public Main(){
    f=new JFrame();
    l1=new JLabel("This is the new Label");
    l1.setBounds(10,20,50,30);
    b1=new JButton("Submit");
    b1.setBounds(50,70,90,40);
    tf1=new JTextField();
    tf1.setBounds(70,100,90,40);

    f.add(l1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.add(tf1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    l1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    //f.setLayout(null);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong in your code is:

You placed f.setVisible(true) before setting the layout for the frame.
Your last lines in the constructor should be like:

```
f.setLayout(null);
f.setSize(500,500);
f.setVisible(true);
```

> setVisible() should be called only after making all the changes you
>   want to,on the frame.

Also remove the line l1.setLayout(). I dont understand why you are setting the layout for label here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked for me.and this l1.setLayout()  was just the testing. Thank-you.